# Special characters in Android

Tags: java, android

In EditText field I set values in Cyrillic alphabet, such as АБГ .. all shows fine.
When I try to set some Greek or any other letter similar to that, such as **'ʎ'** (lambda), **'ƃ'** (not sure where this comes) or **'ɟ'** .. it shows squares like "□ □ □" this.

The charset is UTF-8, otherwise it would not show the Cyrillic alphabet letters...
any ideas on this behavior?

Comment: Generally speaking squares for characters indicate that the system has no matching font to render the desired glyph. So while it probably does recognize the characters, it doesn't know how to draw them.

Comment: then I try to set Incosolata font, which on the system (Ubuntu) shows the characters properly in text editor, while in the EditText it shows empty spaces (instead of squares, now). thanks.

Comment: How did you set the charset of the EditText?

Comment: Technically speaking, Java uses Unicode, not utf-8.  Utf-8 is an encoding, which comes into play when text is read or written from a file; that doesn't apply here.  I don't think you can set the charset of an editText; everything is Unicode.  Joachim is correct; the squares indicate characters missing from the system font.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to create your own custom font with the missing characters.  Ideally, you'd only need to define those specific characters in the font, and then have the system go to the default font for any other characters in your TextView.  I don't know if that happens automatically, or you have to define a "fail-over" font somehow.

Answer (score 0):

That you're able to show cyrillic characters is no guarentee that you're using utf-8. It can also be that you're using charset iso-8859-5 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5)

Comment: Android is Java.  Java uses unicode.  The squares indicate characters missing from Android's built-in unicode fonts.